# Phrase for making an unnecessary purchase before engaging in an activity

Tags: phrase-requests

Is there an expression or phrase to describe the misguided behavior of believing that purchasing an item relating to an activity you *wish* to pursue will give you the motivation to actually *engage* in that activity?

For example, a person who *never* jogs outdoors purchases an expensive treadmill, thinking that purchase will be the impetus to make them "a jogger" rather than simply going for a run outside and maybe buying a treadmill sometime in the future, after they've stuck with it for a while.

Or a person who never bakes will purchase a top-of-the-line stand-mixer, believing they'll begin baking once they own the proper tools, even though they *could* have baked a cake with the equipment they already owned.

The implication here is that this is a false premise; if you don't run or bake now, you're unlikely to make it a regular habit just because bought a fun new toy.  You've made an unnecessary purchase and you still aren't engaging in the activity in question.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of **wishful thinking** / **wishful buying**

> The attribution of reality to what one wishes to be true or the
> tenuous justification of what one wants to believe [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wishful%20thinking)

> In modern use in weaker sense: expressing or indicative of a wish;
> chiefly in **wishful thinking**, thinking, esp. belief or expectation,
> that is influenced by one's wishes to the extent that relevant
> (consciously) known facts are (subconsciously) ignored or distorted;
> also as adj.; so wishful thinker. OED
>
> *He [sc. a prisoner] hoarded these glimpses of past happiness, rationing his **wishful reminiscing** to half an hour a day.*

---

> Joseph Pilates once said, “Physical fitness can neither be achieved by
> **wishful thinking**, not outright purchase.” [Brian Richey; *Back
> Exercise: Stabilize, Mobilize, and Reduce Pain*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Back_Exercise/SwjwDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Joseph%20Pilates%20once%20said,%20Physical%20fitness%20can%20neither%20be%20achieved%20by%20wishful%20thinking&pg=PR2&printsec=frontcover)

> **Wishful thinking** *doesn't work and may be dangerous.*
> Permit me to illustrate the point: I would love to flap my arms and
> fly to the moon. And sometimes I would like it to rain beer. Those
> things are not possible. [Bernard M. Patten *Truth, Knowledge, Or Just
> Plain Bull*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Truth_Knowledge_Or_Just_Plain_Bull/79g2YZV7dMwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22wishful%20thinking%22%20made%20a%20purchase%20thinking&pg=PA11&printsec=frontcover)

For some items we buy but never use, we sometimes say "It's just a **glorified X.**" For example, with regard to exercise equipment:

["Take it away: why fitness machines turn into **clothes hangers**"](https://www.active.com/articles/take-it-away-why-fitness-machines-turn-into-clothes-hangers)

Some are **impulse purchases**, while although others are planned, researched purchases.

**Wishful buying** seems to be rare, but I see no reason not to use it since *wishful* fits the definition.

> The availability of paperbacks has made a difference in the buying of
> books; who can say if it has made an impact upon reading. I know some
> people who do **wishful buying** but never get to reading. [*Wilson
> Library Bulletin*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Wilson_library_bulletin/jZBOAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=I%20know%20some%20people%20who%20do%20wishful%20buying%20but%20never%20get%20to%20reading&dq=I%20know%20some%20people%20who%20do%20wishful%20buying%20but%20never%20get%20to%20reading&printsec=frontcover), Vol.36, p.239

> Yet a case can be made out for the hire-purchase of necessities, as
> distinct from the **wishful buying** of non-essential luxuries [R. Dallas Brett; *Usury in Britain*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22wishful%20buying%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AOaemvLfH6nuJrc0_LOliaLyLxPZmZOXiA%3A1630259194926&ei=-scrYYf3N92q5NoP5IaqmA0&oq=%22wishful%20buying%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i299k1l2.6355.7479.0.7646.6.6.0.0.0.0.149.639.4j2.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.2.246....0.39XMF_RYwW0).

Comment: This is a perfectly valid answer and I very much appreciate the response, so thank you. However, I was hoping for something more specific to the act of making a purchase in pursuit of your wishful thinking. There may not be such an expression, in which case, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @egherrmann I've added examples of "wishful buying."

Comment: The addition of "wishful buying" definitely improves this answer

Answer (score 1):

Technically, I think it's a (failed) [precommitment mechanism](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3465853/).

[Aspirational purchase](https://neologisms.rice.edu/index.php?a=term&d=1&t=21732): A purchase made (often clothing) that isn’t something someone would typically buy, but represent a place or way of life they aspire to be where they would buy things like that all the time. (From Rice.edu, listed as a neologism.)

Somewhat generically: idealistic (purchase) or overly optimistic (purchase).